Cannot figure out how to properly align content with resizing window
I'm trying to create a Godot game that runs in a resizeable window. The larger the window, the more of the game world players should be able to see - i.e. I do not want the game graphics to get scaled up.
The structure of my main scene is as follows:
(A) Node2D
  (B) Camera2D
    (C) Control
  (D) Node2D

(A) is offset by half the viewport width/height as configured in the Project Settings under Display -> Window.
(C) is actually the root of a scene that displays a command bar for controlling the game. It is positioned at the bottom of the viewport.
(D) is the player object.
The camera (B) is set to center on the player object (D) (by means of a RemoteTransform2D).
Dissatisfactory Observation 1
When I run the game, everything looks fine. Once the window is resized (e.g. maximized), the player remains in the center, but I can see a bit more of their surrounding.
However, (C) still has the same position relative to the player object (D). It seems the window gets enlarged to all sides around its former center, rather than e.g. down + right, as I would have intuitively expected.
Now, I can probably reposition (C) programmatically when the window size changes, but I wonder whether I can somehow align (C) automatically to stick to the bottom of the viewport.
I have tried setting anchors_preset for (C) to "Bottom Wide", but that somehow makes (C)'s top left corner snap to the center of the viewport.
Dissatisfactory Observation 2
As some kind of an (almost) screen-filling pop-up, I instantiate a MarginContainer (with the same margin width on all sides) with some controls inside, set its anchors_preset to "Full Rect", and attach it directly to GetTree().Root (i.e. the window itself). This works well in the window's original size.
Once I maximize the window, however, the margin on the right and bottom is gone, and the margin on the left and top have grown considerably, as if the MarginPanel were not anchored to the window at all and had been shifted right and down a bit.

How do I properly anchor my UI controls to a resizeable window?

I will assume you already know / have watched a YouTube tutorial on how to use Anchors and Containers to correctly layout a GUI (since these are GUI elements, it will be much easier to watch a video than describe it in text).
--
That said the way I typically create my GUI's is to create a new scene (select the 'User Interface' option).
That creates a Control node as the root of the scene - which allows me to layout all the containers and controls as I need them. Then in my main game scene I add a CanvasLayer as a child of the root of the scene and then I add my GUI scene as a child of the CanvasLayer
I don't think it is required to create a separate scene for your GUI, however if you choose to keep everything in one scene, I think you will still need to add a CanvasLayer as the parent of all of your GUI elements.

Thank you, a CanvasLayer with follow_viewport_enabled set to false yields exactly the result I was after.

Make UI the root.

The structure you have:
(A) Node2D
  (B) Camera2D
    (C) Control

Is telling me that the Control (C) will be centered on the screen (i.e. centered on the Camera2D (B)), which is following some object (A).
If you wanted to put a health bar over the head of a character, you might do something like that. Otherwise, don't.

The Node2d (A and B) do not have an inherent size (I know there are caveats to that statement, but they do not change what I'm saying). Because of that the Control (C) does not have bounds to align to. Because of this, setting anchors won't be useful.
However, if the Control (C) is a child of the Viewport (e.g. the Window) then it does.
I'm not sure what you were doing with the MarginContainer but it seems you set the preset before adding as a child of the root of the scene tree.

Instead, set some Control (perhaps C) as the root of your current scene. And inside of it you can add your world (Node2D, Camera2D) etc.
You are likely to run into other issues with scaling. Notably you might want to scale the UI independently from the game world (in fact, you mention you do not want the game graphics to get scaled up)... To address that I'm currently using a ViewportContainer with a SubViewport inside. Yes, they have an overhead, but even in mobile you can afford a couple of these, and a lot more on PC. Another solution is to split the UI from the game world using CanvasLayer. I do not know if that works better for what you are trying to do.
See here for the way I structure my main scene.
Addendum: After writing the answer I notice that when you say "game graphics" I'm assuming you mean the game world, but you might mean the UI as well. In that case, I believe changing the scale mode on project setting should suffice, and you probably don't need to use a SubViewport.

No no, by "game graphics", I was indeed referring to the game world. Thanks, very helpful approaches, I'll try, then report back here.

I have chosen the solution with the CanvasLayer for now, so I'll accept the other answer, but upvote this one as it is also very enlightening. Thank you!
